# YouTrack "vcs changes" search

Tags: youtrack

Overall I'm trying to do a search for what has changed since a given date, based on actual VCS changes. If I do the search:

```
updated: 2018-01 .. 2018-02
```

It will give me lots of hits that just have comments, added tags, etc.. I want issues with actual commits connected to them.

I'm on YouTrack 2017.4 (Build 39406 9 Feb 2018 00:00) and If I start typing "vcs changes" it clearly has a search term for it, but I only get exceptions when trying to search by it. I'm not sure this solves my problem, but it does seem like something I'm interested in.

How can I successfully do a search using the "vcs changes" term?

My YouTrack is using TeamCity integration. For example if searching for `vcs changes: a`, I get this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method jetbrains.youtrack.search.keyword.predefined.PredefinedField.filter, parameter filterField
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.keyword.predefined.PredefinedField.filter(PredefinedField.kt)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.IssuesSearchRequestExecutor.getValue(IssuesSearchRequestExecutor.java:42)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.IssuesSearchRequestExecutor.getValue(IssuesSearchRequestExecutor.java:26)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.appendCategorizedValueIssues(SearchRequestExecutor.java:246)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.filterRequestTerm(SearchRequestExecutor.java:173)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.filterAndOperand(SearchRequestExecutor.java:105)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.filterAndExpression(SearchRequestExecutor.java:92)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.filterOrExpression(SearchRequestExecutor.java:81)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.filterSearchRequest(SearchRequestExecutor.java:73)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.SearchRequestExecutor.filter(SearchRequestExecutor.java:49)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.search.parser.ParseResult.getParseErrors(ParseResult.java:99)
    at jetbrains.charisma.smartui.filter.FilterData.getParseErrors(FilterData.java:78)
    at jetbrains.charisma.smartui.persistent.UserSearchRequest.search(UserSearchRequest.java:61)
    at jetbrains.charisma.smartui.workspace.Issues_RootHtmlTemplateComponent.onEnter(Issues_RootHtmlTemplateComponent.java:233)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.templateComponent.TemplateComponent.<init>(TemplateComponent.java:95)
    at jetbrains.charisma.smartui.workspace.Issues_RootHtmlTemplateComponent.<init>(Issues_RootHtmlTemplateComponent.java:122)
    at jetbrains.charisma.smartui.workspace.Issues_RootHtmlTemplateController$Action.createTemplateComponent(Issues_RootHtmlTemplateController.java:55)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.templateComponent.TemplateActionController.getRootTemplateRenderResponseAction(TemplateActionController.java:92)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.templateComponent.TemplateActionController.doEnterAction(TemplateActionController.java:60)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.templateComponent.ActionController.securedRefreshResponse(ActionController.java:158)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.templateComponent.ActionController.enterAction(ActionController.java:83)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.requestProcessor.ActionControllerUtil.doEnterAction(ActionControllerUtil.java:17)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.requestProcessor.ActionControllerUtil.processRequest(ActionControllerUtil.java:60)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.requestProcessor.HtmlTemplateRequestProcessor.processRequest(HtmlTemplateRequestProcessor.java:42)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.servlet.MainServlet.processRequest(MainServlet.java:235)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.servlet.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:151)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.ClearThreadLocalPrincipalFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalPrincipalFilters.kt:13)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.FilterAdapter.doFilter(FilterAdapter.kt:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.RootGoFilter.doFilter(RootGoFilter.kt:60)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.FilterAdapter.doFilter(FilterAdapter.kt:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.SetThreadLocalPrincipalFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalPrincipalFilters.kt:29)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.FilterAdapter.doFilter(FilterAdapter.kt:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.WebrSessionAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebrSessionAuthenticationFilter.kt:40)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.FilterAdapter.doFilter(FilterAdapter.kt:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at jetbrains.mps.webr.runtime.filter.QueryParameterFilter.doFilter(QueryParameterFilter.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter.doFilter(ContinuationFilter.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.SecurityResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecurityResponseHeadersFilter.kt:18)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.FilterAdapter.doFilter(FilterAdapter.kt:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.SearchEngineIndexBotAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SearchEngineIndexBotAuthenticationFilter.kt:55)
    at jetbrains.youtrack.webapp.filters.FilterAdapter.doFilter(FilterAdapter.kt:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It seems like a bug in YouTrack. Try posting it to their issue tracker instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `vcs changes` as an attribute, follow it up with the full commit hash to find issues that include this VCS change.

To find issues that contain VCS commits, `has: {vcs changes}` will do the trick.